# I think there's something I'm confused about with the variables

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, variables, min

```
#include<stdio.h>
void Multi(int num1, int num2)
{
    int a, b;
    if (num1 < num2)
        a = num1, b = num2;
    else
        a = num2, b = num1;
    for (a; a > b; a++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            printf("%d * %d = %d \n", a, i, a * i);
    } 
};
int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    printf("enter two numbers :\n");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &a, &b);
    Dan(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Both of these programs do not execute the For statement. I think there's some problem with the variables.

Comment: what means "do not execute "?

Comment: We may have a miscommunication problem here. You say *"Both of these programs"* yet only posted one program. Did you mean "functions" instead?

Comment: What is `Dan`? Where do you call `Multi`? When creating a [mcve] please make sure that it only replicates the problem you ask about.

Comment: @Mike No problem, it's rather bad style to use the comma expression like that. Makes the code much harder to read and understand (as you noticed ;) ).

Answer (score 4):

This for loop (the body of the loop)

```
 for (a; a > b; a++)
```

is never executed because in the preceding code `a` is set such a way that it is less than or equal to `b`. So `a > b` always evaluates to false.

You need to write either

```
for ( ; a < b; a++)
```

or

```
for ( ; a <= b; a++)
```

Also it would be more safer to write the call of `printf` the following way

```
printf("%d * %d = %lld \n", a, i, ( long long )a * i);
```